# How to add Schema.org tags to hotel rooms?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'm creating a website for a hotel. This hotel has different types of rooms(luxury, non smoking, kids etc). How can I add schema.org tags to rooms listing? I found this one but, it gives errors when I test it using Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Room">
  <span itemprop="hasLodgingProvider" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel"><span
itemprop="name">The Sunshine Hotel</span> </span>offers both <span itemprop="hasRoomType" itemscope
itemtype="http://schema.org/RoomType"><span itemprop="name">King</span> and
<span itemprop="name">Double</span></span>, both of which feature <span itemprop="hasAmenity" itemscope
itemtype="http://schema.org/GuestRoomAmenity"><span itemprop="name">in-room Wifi</span></span>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using types and properties that don’t exist in Schema.org (as of [2.2](https://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.2)).

But types and properties for (hotel) rooms are proposed, see [Markup for Hotels **(work in progress, not a stable URL!)**](http://sdo-hotels.appspot.com/docs/hotels.html). So we might see these (or something similar) in the next Schema.org release.

If you don’t want to wait, the best you could come up with now might be to use the generic `Place` for rooms:

- [`Hotel`](http://schema.org/Hotel) [`containsPlace`](http://schema.org/containsPlace) [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place)
- [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place) [`containedInPlace`](http://schema.org/containedInPlace) [`Hotel`](http://schema.org/Hotel)

Comment: Thank you @unor. I will try that  :)

Answer (score 1):

The schema.org release of version 3.1 finally brought the hotel extension to annotate hotel rooms. The documentation (http://schema.org/docs/hotels.html) is not yet up to date, but you can find an example of how to annotate a hotel and its rooms here: https://elias.kaerle.com/annotating-a-hotel-offering-rooms-with-the-new-schema-org-version-3-1/ (this example annotates the rooms as offers of the hotel Hotel-makesOffer-Offer - Offer-itemOffered-HotelRoom).